# get status code from a gRPC endpoint not using a gRPC client

Tags: amazon-web-services, grpc

How could I get the [status code](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html) from a gRPC endpoint without having a gRPC client?

I need to test some [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) endpoints that are behind an [AWS application load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-support-for-end-to-end-http-2-and-grpc/) (`target group`) with a health check configured to only accept status `12`

```
UNIMPLEMENTED   12  The operation is not implemented or is not supported/enabled in this service.
```

I tried `grpcurl` for example:

`grpcurl -plaintext 10.1.2.8:8443 AWS.ALB/healthcheck`:

But in many cases I get:

```
Error invoking method "AWS.ALB/healthcheck": failed to query for service descriptor "AWS.ALB": server does not support the reflection API
```

Any alternatives or ideas? I am just interested in the status code `12` or description `UNIMPLEMENTED`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: not the best but I created this https://crates.io/crates/grpc-status

Comment: `12` means target group health check response code. We set it to 0 in our server

Answer (score 0):

For status code `12`, you can change it through

```
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '0'      // change success code to 0
spec:
  rules:
    - host: server.xxx.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*                                 // set to * to match all grpc service paths
            backend:
              serviceName: server
              servicePort: 9420
```

Also enable [server reflection](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/server-reflection-tutorial.md#enable-server-reflection)

```
@@ -40,6 +40,7 @@ import (
        "google.golang.org/grpc"
        pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"
+       "google.golang.org/grpc/reflection"
 )

 const (
@@ -61,6 +62,8 @@ func main() {
        }
        s := grpc.NewServer()
        pb.RegisterGreeterService(s, &pb.GreeterService{SayHello: sayHello})
+       // Register reflection service on gRPC server.
+       reflection.Register(s)
        if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
        }
```